# Undo email wordwrap line breaks in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, email

My Rails app processes incoming emails by splitting them into multiple lines. This is what I currently use on the plain text version of the body: `lines = email.body.split("\n")`

This works well unless the sentences are longer than ~74 characters as most email clients will  automatically add a line break per [RFC 2822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt).

Example email: https://gist.github.com/marckohlbrugge/39c17b928eb17d330d63

Looking at the plain text part there seems to be no way to discern between a line break added by the user versus the email client. You could ignore any line break happening at the 75th position, but I think there might be a chance of false positives. (I could be wrong.)

The HTML part has all the information we need, but I'm not sure about a universal way to process this. Is replacing every `div` and `br` with a newline and then stripping al other HTML elements enough? What about all the other block-element tags? What about inline elements styled as block-elements? What if an email doesn't have an HTML part?

I did find some interesting code examples in [Convert HTML to plain text (with inclusion of 
s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10144739/convert-html-to-plain-text-with-inclusion-of-brs), but replacing a list of html tags with newlines doesn't seem like a complete (exhaustive) solution.

Answer (score 1):

Is it worth looking at something like [this mail library](https://github.com/mikel/mail) as they've probably already thought about the edge cases? ;)

Comment: Yeah I looked at some of those libraries, but came up empty.